# Customizing the 'ApplicationUser' to hold more user data in ASP.NET Angular template (dotnet core 3.0)

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.0

I am currently working on an ASP.NET Web app with angular as a front end. As a base, the new template present in VisualStudio 2019 for ASP.NET angular, with Individual Authentication.

This run on dotnet core 3.0 Preview 4.

[image]

What I am trying to do is to add some user data to the default ApplicationUser.
Say my ApplicationUser is a student, I would like the student to be taking multiple classes, and each classes have multiple assignments.

ApplicationUser --> * Class --> * Assignment

To do so I have created the modes for the Class and Assignment and have added the relationships like so

example in ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{ 
    public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}
```

example in Class:

```
public class Class
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double CurrentGrade
    {
        get
        {
            if (Assignments.Count == 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            double grade = 0;
            foreach (Assignment a in Assignments)
            {
                grade += (a.Weight * a.Score);
            }

            return grade;
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }

    public Class()
    {
        Assignments = new List<Assignment>();
    }

}
```

and example in Assignment:

```
public class Assignment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Class FromClass { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Weight
    {
        get { return Weight; }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 0 || value > 100)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The weight of the assignment should be between 0 and 100");
            }
            Weight = value;
        }
    }
    public double Score
    {
        get { return Score; }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 0 || value > 100)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The score of the assignment should be between 0 and 100");
            }

            Score = value;
        }
    }

    public Assignment()
    {

    }

    public Assignment(string name, double weight, double score)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Weight = weight;
        this.Score = score;
    }

}
```

This way I have added the virtual tags to define the relationships between the classes.

Finally, the *ApplicationDbContext* class was modified such that the tables for the new entities are generates (from my understanding)

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public virtual DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(
            DbContextOptions options,
            IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {

    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Invoke the Identity version of this method to configure relationships 
        // in the AspNetIdentity models/tables
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Add a configuration for our new table.  Choose one end of the relationship
        // and tell it how it's supposed to work
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(e => e.Classes);        // ApplicationUser has many Classes

        modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().HasMany(e => e.Assignments); 
    }


}
```

I believe that this is all that is needed achieve this but maybe something is missing.

My main issue now is the registration page. The template project already has the login and register functionality built in. I would like to modify the register page such that when a user registers, it can specify what classes it is currently signed in. Such that when its ApplicationUser is created and saved in the Identity table, the classes that the user (student) is taking are also created and saved in the database as well.

Template registration page that needs to be modified:
[image]

The issue is that in the template, the html/typescript files handling this are nowhere to be found. Would anyone know how I could go about modifying this page to fit the application? (It would also be nice to get rid of the 'User another service to register' generic text.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default login pages by scaffolding the "Identity".

Right-click on your project in Solution Explorer and then select: Add->New Scaffolded Item->Identity

Then click Add. You can choose which pages you want to override (or just choose all). The pages will be created in the "Areas/Identity" folder.

Comment: That worked great, I can now edit the default pages for the log in etc, however, all file that were generated are html files. I can then add to the form in the cshtml file for registering to have my extra field 'Name' but how does does this ensure that the ApplicationUser will have this property? @CarloBoggio

Comment: I was able to find the cs file that is soociated to the cshtml file to add the logic necessary to save the Application user with its newly created 'Name' filed. Thank you